# Iterate over template pack that checks if instance is of a particular variant

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I want some reusable code where I can pass a variant instance and a bunch of types and check if the instance is of that type at compile time. And if not, maybe return something like `nullopt`.

In pseudo-code, ideally it would be something like this:

```cpp
template <typename ...Ts>
auto getType(const std::variant<Ts...>& v)
{
    for (auto T : Ts)
        if (std::holds_alternative<T>(v)
            return std::get<T>(v);
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

and then I should hopefully be able to use it like this:

```cpp
if (auto v = getType<type_a, type_b>(foo.param))
{
    // ... do something with v here
}
else if (auto v = getType<type_c>(foo.param))
{
    // ... do something else with v here
}
```

I'm not an experienced C++ dev and I'm coming back to C++ after not having used it for years and some of the stuff that has been added to the language since is a little over my head. Apparently I can accomplish this with fold expressions, but the examples I've seen (e.g. [here](https://foonathan.net/2020/05/fold-tricks/) or [here](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/3208/iterating-over-a-parameter-pack)) I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around. Is what I want possible at all?

Comment: Instead of a chain of `else-if`s, you could just use `std::visit`.

Comment: A function has to return a specific type defined in compile-time. So your `getType` can only return `variant` or something like it, your best bet is something like `std::visit`.

Comment: @yeputons yeah, but this is not a function. This is a *function template*. You may as well write it so for certain `variant`s it'll return some type, and for others it will return something completely unrelated. Like `void`, for instance.

Comment: @Fureeish my colleagues are not comfortable with `std::visit` as they consider it a little too magical, also, the code under each if statement is somewhat involved, so not sure if that won't impact readability (the examples I can see with `std::visit` all suggest a straightforward dispatch table-style of programming). Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Fureeish consider `std::variant<int, std::string>`. The `getType` function then should return something which can contain both `int` and `std::string`. I.e. something `std::variant`-like.

Comment: @Nobilis What is the exact expected return type of `gegtType<type_a, type_b>`? For `getType<type_c>` it can be `std::optional<type_c>` (and then `getType` is a simple wrapper around `holds_alternative` and `get`).

Comment: @yeputons I guess it would be whichever type is currently held or if none of them are held, I thought `nullopt` is a decent default here. But perhaps that's not possible at compile time?

Comment: @Nobilis Yes, you have to decide the return type of `getType<type_a, type_b>` at compile time in C++.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. All functions, whether generated by template, or not, must return a single, defined, specific type. This is a core fundamental rule in C++ that cannot be changed. As described, your desired function may return different types based on a runtime condition. C++ does not work this way. What you are ***really*** looking for is `std::visit`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik well, technically you can do Return Type Resolver, but I doubt it will help here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik right, fair, thank you, looks like there's no other way around it

Comment: @yeputons correct, I was under the (wrong) impression that we were talking about different `variant`s, not `variant`s that simply hold different active values inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
std::optional<std::variant<Ts...>> getType(const std::variant<Ts...>& v)
{
    std::optional<std::variant<Ts...>> res;

    ((res = !res && std::holds_alternative<Ts>(v) ? std::get<Ts>(v) : std::nullopt), ...);
    return res;
}
```

but it is mostly pointless, as you have then again to dispatch for the new variant.

`std::visit` is the way to go:

```
std::visit(overloaded{
    ([](type_a& v){})
    {
    // ... do something with v here
    },
    ([](type_a& v){})
    {
    // ... do something with v here
    },
    ([](type_c& v){})
    {
    // ... do something with v here
    }
    ([](auto& v){}) // fallback: other types
    {
    // ... do something with v here
    }
    }, foo.param);
```

Comment: Right, thank you, coming back to your `std::visit` example, if say `type_a` and `type_b` could be handled equivalently, would I still need to just duplicate the code for both types or is there a way to group them here?

Comment: What is that `T` in your first snippet of code? In the "[...] `? std::get<T>(v) : ` [...]". Typo of `Ts`?

Comment: @Nobilis you would have to provide an overload for both. The thing is, you can define a named type which would use private methods to delegate the specific work and you could reuse that, and overload `operator()` for them.